# Derivative of the Cholesky factor

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, vectorization

I have a symmetric positive definite matrix $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and its Cholesky factor $G\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $L=GG^T$. Called $\mathrm{vec}:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ the vectorization operator, and $K_{n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n^2}$ the commutation matrix, i.e. the permutation matrix realizing $\mathrm{vec}(M)=K\mathrm{vec}(M^T)$ for $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I know I can get
$$
\frac{\partial \mathrm{vec}(L)}{\partial \mathrm{vec}(G)} = (I_{n^2}+K)(G\otimes I_n),
$$
where $I_k\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ stands for the identity matrix. My goal would be to compute the derivative of the vectorization of the Cholesky factor $G$ with respect to the original matrix $L$. However, the matrix $I_{n^2}+K$ is singular, since $K$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue.

Is there a way to compute the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial \mathrm{vec}(G)}{\partial\mathrm{vec}(L)}?
$$

Comment: Isn't this the same issue as computing $dx/dy$ for $y=x^2$? How do you write the inverse function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}} \def\f{\frac12}
\def\h{\odot}  \def\k{\otimes}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\D{\Delta}
$Let $P$ denote a matrix whose elements are all $\tt1$ below the diagonal, $\tfrac12$ on the diagonal, and $0$ above the diagonal, e.g.
$$
P=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\f & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\o & \f & 0 & 0 \\
\o & \o & \f & 0 \\
\o & \o & \o & \f \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
This $P$ matrix can disentangle the symmetrized product
of lower triangular matrices $(A,B)$
$$\eqalign{
\def\AT{A^{-T}}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\BT{B^{-T}}
\def\B{B^{-1}}
F = AB^T + BA^T
 &\qiq &B = A\,\BR{P\h\LR{\A F\AT}} \\
&&({\rm assuming\ }\A\ {\rm exists})
}$$
This has obvious applications to your problem
$$\eqalign{
\def\GT{G^{-T}}
\def\G{G^{-1}}
L &= GG^T \\
dL &= G\,dG^T + dG\,G^T
 \qquad\; \{{\rm differential\ of}\ L\}\\
dG &= G\,\BR{P\h\LR{\G\,dL\:\GT}} \\
\vc{dG}
 &= \LR{I\k G}\,\vc{P\h\LR{\G\,dL\:\GT}} \\
 &= \LR{I\k G}\,\Diag{\vc P}\,\vc{\G\,dL\:\GT} \\
 &= \LR{I\k G}\,\Diag{\vc P}\,\LR{\G\k\G}\:\vc{dL} \\
\grad{\vc G}{\vc L}
 &= \LR{I\k G}\,\Diag{\vc P}\,\LR{\G\k\G} \\
}$$

---

In the above, $\h$ is the Hadamard product and $\k$ is the Kronecker product.

Comment: Very interesting approach, thanks! Is there any reference (like books) where I can read about these ideas/techniques. I've never seen them, since every source I read where the vec operator is considered, only very simple properties are presented.

Comment: @Dadeslam I can't recall the journal article (several years ago) where I originally saw the $P$ matrix.  As for book recommendations, the standard text is probably 
Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_,
although personally I prefer 
Hjorungnes's _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_.

For looking up formulas, if you cannot find it in
Petersen and Pedersen's [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)
then consult
Bernstein's _Matrix Mathematics: Theory, Facts, and Formulas_

Comment: Amazing, thank you again!